# During xmr-stak install (Monero Mining) I get CUDA TOOLKIT ERROR?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, cuda

Here's the [tutorial](https://www.cryptocurrencyfreak.com/2017/08/22/monero-mining-xmr-stak-cpu-ubuntu-16-04/).

After

```
cd xmr-stak-cpu
```

and

```
sudo cmake
```

I get this error:

```
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5") CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:209 (message): CUDA NOT found: use -DCUDA_ENABLE=OFF to build without NVIDIA GPU support
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/local/src/xmr-stak/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`
```

I tried:

```
sudo cmake
```

Once more, got a little different error:

```
-- Set miner currency to 'monero' and 'aeon'
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing:  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:209 (message):
  CUDA NOT found: use -DCUDA_ENABLE=OFF to build without NVIDIA GPU support`
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/usr/local/src/xmr-stak/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

---

I tried to install NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit from [Nvidia website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=deblocal) with the following errors:

*-> runfile[local]*

```
$ sudo sh cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run
[sudo] password for username: 
sh: 0: Can't open cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run
```

*-> deb[local]*

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-1-local_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
dpkg: Error while processing the archive cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-1-local_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb (--install):    
The archive can not be accessed: file or directory not found    
Errors occurred while processing:    
cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-1-local_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Have you installed Cuda?

Comment: Seems not, that's why I tried to install Cuda with the results you see in my edit above.

Comment: 1. You can only install Cuda if you have a compatible Nvidia card supporting the required Nvidia driver version. 2. Regardless of the p[revious point it seems you're issuing command in the wrong directory, files must exist in your current directory.

Comment: I guess I have to download it first, before I can use the sudo-commands, right? (yes, I got Nvidia card)

Answer (score 0):

> sh: 0: Can't open cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run

Because the download from the nVidia website strangely does not include the `.run` extension. Try replacing the command with:

`$ sudo sh cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux`

or rename the file to include the .run extension.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases at the end of your question, *-> runfile[local]* and *-> deb[local]*, you are getting errors for the same reason, you have not provided the full path to either cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run or cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-1-local_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb respectively. To show the full path to a file, drag the file's icon from the file manager into the terminal. Alternatively you can change directories with `cd` to the directory containing the file before running either of the two commands. For example if a file is located in your Downloads directory, the command to change directories to the file's parent directory is: `cd ~/Downloads`